# How to change the rule color in cals table

Tags: table-of-contents, cals

I make a table using cals package, I want to modify the width of the table using  colwidths , when I rewrite the value in this code:\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*4\relax}, the table widen to the right ,how could I make it widen to the left and right? And if I want to change the rule color to the RGB:221, 216, 195, how could I modify the code? Here is my code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, UTF8]{ctexrep}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cals, caption}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{st_table_blue}{RGB}{87, 142, 210}
\definecolor{gridcolor}{RGB}{221, 216, 195}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table\label{tabelTable}}

\begin{calstable}[c]
%\arrayrulecolor{gridcolor}

% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            %{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/25*6\relax}
    }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 6

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
%\def\cals@framers@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@framers@width{0.2pt}    % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@framers@color{gridcolor}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}             % Ensure that all cells is vertically centred
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}


\def\lblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    %\def\cals@bgcolor{LightSteelBlue}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{st_table_blue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1H1
\thead{\footnotesize\bfseries
\brow
    \lblue\nc{lrt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Heading spanning three columns}
    \nc{lrt}
\erow
%R2H2
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{Text}
    %\cell{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{Subheading is long and that wraps}}
    \cell{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{FDA/NMPA\\批准于本癌种}}
    \cell{Short}
    \cell{Subheading that wraps}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{Text}\lblue
\erow
\mdseries}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R3B1
\brow
    \alignC\cell{Wrapping text}

    %\cell{Horiz. and vertic. centred}
    \alignC\cell{阿法替尼*，达克替尼*， 奥西替尼*，吉非替尼*，埃克替尼*，厄洛替尼*，阿美替尼*}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{3}
    \cell{1}
\erow
%R3B1
\brow
    \alignC\cell{1}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{3}
    \cell{1}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}
\end{table}




\end{document}
```

and the result is as picture [image]
I want the picture like this [image]

Comment: The `xcolor` package provides the necessary commands to produce tables with alternate row colors, when loaded with the table option. The command `\rowcolors{<''starting row''>}{<''odd color''>}{<''even color''>}` has to be specified right before the tabular environment starts.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50377/108724

Comment: @C.F.G I want to change the border color not the cell color

Comment: `\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl} ` then `\arrayrulecolor{red}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope the below modified `MWE` meets your requirement:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, UTF8]{ctexrep}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ctex}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{cals, caption}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{st_table_blue}{RGB}{87, 142, 210}
\definecolor{gridcolor}{RGB}{221, 216, 195}

\let\nc=\nullcell                                                  % Shortcuts
\let\sc=\spancontent

\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\cals@cs@outOne[3]{%
\ifx \relax#1%
\else
 \cals@withColorII\cals@bgcolor{#3}\iftrue
  \textcolor{\cals@color}{\vrule depth0pt width#1 }%
  \hskip -#1\relax
 \fi
\fi
\cals@withWidthII\cals@cs@width{#2}\iftrue
 \cals@halfWidthToDimen0 \cals@width %
 \hskip -\dimen0 %
 \color{white}\vrule depth0pt width\cals@width\relax
 \hskip -\dimen0 %
\fi
\let\cals@lastLeftWidth=\cals@width
\ifx \relax#1\else \hskip#1 \fi
}

\renewcommand\cals@rs@sofar@out{%
\ifdim 0pt=\cals@rs@sofar@width\relax
  \hskip\cals@rs@sofar@length\relax
\else
  \cals@halfWidthToDimen0\cals@rs@sofar@borderl
  \hskip-\dimen0\relax
  \cals@halfWidthToDimen2\cals@rs@sofar@borderr
  \dimen4=\cals@rs@sofar@length\relax
  \advance\dimen4 by \dimen0\relax \advance\dimen4 by \dimen2\relax
  \cals@halfWidthToDimen6\cals@rs@sofar@width
 \color{white}\vrule height\dimen6 depth\dimen6 width\dimen4\relax
  \hskip-\dimen2\relax
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{table}
\caption{A table\label{tabelTable}}

\begin{calstable}[c]

% Defining columns relative to each other and relative to the margins
\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            %{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/25*6\relax}
    }
% The tabular fills the text area if sum of all columns is 6

% Set up the tabular
\makeatletter
%\def\cals@framers@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@framers@width{0.2pt}    % Outside frame rules, reduce if the rule is too heavy
\def\cals@framecs@width{0.2pt}
\def\cals@framers@color{gridcolor}
\def\cals@bgcolor{}
\def\cals@AtBeginCell{\vfil}             % Ensure that all cells is vertically centred
\setlength{\cals@paddingL}{3pt}
\setlength{\cals@paddingR}{3pt}


\def\lblue{\ifx\cals@bgcolor\empty     % "Switch" to turn on and off colour
    %\def\cals@bgcolor{LightSteelBlue}
    \def\cals@bgcolor{st_table_blue}
\else \def\cals@bgcolor{} \fi}


% R1H1
\thead{\footnotesize\bfseries
\brow
    \lblue\nc{lrt}
    \nc{ltb}
    \nc{tb}
    \nc{rtb}\alignC\sc{Heading spanning three columns}
    \nc{lrt}
\erow
%R2H2
\brow
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{Text}
    %\cell{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{Subheading is long and that wraps}}
    \cell{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{FDA/NMPA\\??????}}
    \cell{Short}
    \cell{Subheading that wraps}
    \nc{lrb}\alignC\sc{Text}\lblue
\erow
\mdseries}
\tfoot{\lastrule\strut}
%R3B1
\brow
    \alignC\cell{Wrapping text}

    %\cell{Horiz. and vertic. centred}
    \alignC\cell{????*,????*, ????*,????*,????*,????*,????*}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{3}
    \cell{1}
\erow
%R3B1
\brow
    \alignC\cell{1}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{2}
    \cell{3}
    \cell{1}
\erow
\makeatletter
\end{calstable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. it works for me.But I have another trouble, if I want to modify the width of the table, I modify colwidths , when I rewrite the value in this code, the table widen to the right ,how could I make it widen to the left and right？@MadyYuvi

Comment: @GuoFengWang How you increase the width? Can you post a revised `MWE`?

Comment: @GuoFengWang Also may I know why you use this table format particularly? As it can be done easily by using normal `tabular`

Comment: I modify the value in this code `\colwidths{{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*4\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*12\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            %{\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/34*6\relax}
            {\dimexpr(\columnwidth)/25*6\relax}
    }`, I use this format cause when I use tabular, the text in the table can not be centered vertically and horizontally @MadyYuvi